# Save integer value as a byte value in char in ansi c

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, mmap

I want to save a ppm file as a P6. That mean bytes only. Also I want to save it in parallel way, so this is why I am using `mmap` to map memory.

This is a part of code where I am trying to save everything:

```
        char* map;
        //...    
        int offset = sprintf(map,"P6\n%d %d\n%d\n",x,y,k);
        int counter = offset;

        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                   for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
                   {
                        map[counter] = outputRed[i][j];
                        map[counter+1] = outputGreen[i][j];
                        map[counter+2] = outputBlue[i][j];
                        counter++;
                   }
            }
```

The problem is that I am unable to save those values from Red, green and blue array (all are int) into map values.

Earlier I've simply used `fputc` with `fopen(FILE,"wb")` and that was doing everything nice, but now I cannot do it like this.

Can someone tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increment the counter by `3` for each pixel:

```
map[counter] = outputRed[i][j];
map[counter+1] = outputGreen[i][j];
map[counter+2] = outputBlue[i][j];
counter += 3;
```

Comment: but why by 3? Because now I am getting segmentation fault

Comment: @sebap123: Each pixel is stored as *three bytes*. - If you get a segmentation fault then there is probably an error in calculating the size of the memory map.

Comment: I am calculating the size of a map like that: `int filesize = x*y*sizeof(char);`

Comment: @sebap123: You need *three bytes* for each pixel. Plus the size of the file header (the `sprintf` part in your code).

Comment: @sebap123 `sizeof(char)` is *guaranteed* to be 1 by the C language standard, there's never any need to ever multiply by it.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I forget about header. I've multiplied also filesize by 3. My only concern now is how to get sprintf size, before writing it.

Comment: @sebap123: You can write it to a separate character buffer first and determine the length.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the counter after copying data for each pixel. This may be more easy to understand.

```
map[counter++] = outputRed[i][j];
map[counter++] = outputGreen[i][j];
map[counter++] = outputBlue[i][j];
```

Make sure the enough memory is allocated to map.